# Apply negative look-ahead to preceeding group

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying since hours to get this negative-look-ahead to work for me. It should match my string only if it's NOT followed by '/CCC'

```
/(^[\w]+)(?!./CCC$)/mg
```

Test string:

```
BBB/CCC
AAA/DDD/CCC
```

Could someone point out why my pattern still matches the 'BBB' of the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to escape the `/` inside the regular expression.

You also have a dot that shouldn't be there and are missing a word boundary:

```
/(^\w+)\b(?!\/CCC$)/mg
```

Comment: Didn't know that the / has to be escaped. None of the regex editors I tried showed it as error. I used the single dot as I thought it will ensure that the '/CCC' is preceeded by at least one 'any char'. Your first version doesn't work for me, only the 2nd. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user640916, the slash is only special because it's being used as the regex delimiter.  Some regex flavors, like Perl and PHP, allow you to choose different characters to use as delimiters, and many other flavors don't require delimiters at all.  Most regex *editors* also don't require delimiters, so they treat the slash as what it is: just another character.